# Access correct "this" from callback function in array of functions inside an object

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to access “helperFunction” from inside a function in “steps” array.  Obviously using “this” doesn’t refer to the correct object but I can’t seem to work out the proper solution.

```
const bannerAnimation = {
    property: 0,
    steps: [
        function one() {
            this.property = this.helperFunction();
        },
        function two() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    ],
    helperFunction() {
        // do some calculations and return the result
        return 1;
    },
    doSteps(steps = this.steps) {
        steps.forEach(step => {
            setTimeout(step, 100);
        });
    }
};

bannerAnimation.doSteps();
```

All help much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achiever this by using `bind` inside the callback to `setTimeout` to correctly bind the `this` to the correct context.

```js
const bannerAnimation = {
    property: 0,
    steps: [
        function one() {
            this.property = this.helperFunction();
        },
        function two() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    ],
    helperFunction() {
        // do some calculations and return the result
        return 1;
    },
    doSteps(steps = this.steps) {
        var self = this;
        steps.forEach(step => {
            setTimeout(step.bind(self), 100);
        });
    }
};

bannerAnimation.doSteps();
```

Comment: @nickzoum but `this.property = ...` wouldn't.